# Finding which quadrant a sum of arctan functions lies in.

Tags: trigonometry

I have a problem telling me to evaluate the following equation

$\arctan(2) + \arctan(5) + \arctan(8)$

I can easily solve it by using the double angle identity for tan, but when trying to find whether the angle is pi/4 or 5pi/4 I find myself unable to do this.

Usually I would evaluate the quadrant by using sin(a+b) to get whether sin is negative or positive at the value, then based on whether tan is negative or positive I can deduce what quadrant my angle lies in.

When using sin(a+b) for this question however I get a positive value for sin, even though the summation of the arctan functions is 5pi/4.

(To use sin(a+b) I turn arctan 2 and arctan 5 into arctan -7/9 using the sum identity for tan, then I use the sum identity for sin and tan to try to evaluate the full expression)

Also I know this can be done with complex numbers but if possible I’m looking for a way using the compound identities.

Comment: Suppose $1<x<\infty$. Then $\pi/4<\arctan(x)< \pi/2$. 

So $3\pi /4<\arctan(x)+ \arctan(y)+\arctan(z)< 3\pi /2$. So $5 \pi /4$ is the only remaining option.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed thank you this is a really straightforward explanation!

Comment: That is not an equation as it does not equal anything specific. It is an expression.

Answer (score 2):

$$\arctan2 + \arctan5 + \arctan8\\=\pi+ \arctan \frac{7}{1-10} +\arctan8\,\\=\pi-\arctan \frac{7}{9}+\arctan8\\=\pi +\arctan \frac{8-\frac{7}{9}}{1+\frac{56}9}=\frac{5\pi}4$$

> Identities,
>
> > $\arctan x+\arctan y=\begin{cases}\arctan \frac{x+y}{1-xy};\quad xy<1\\\pi + \arctan \frac{x+y}{1-xy};\quad xy>1\\\frac {\pi}2;\quad xy=1 \end{cases}$

> > $\arctan x-\arctan y=\begin{cases}\arctan \frac{x-y}{1+xy};\quad xy>-1\\\pi + \arctan \frac{x+y}{1-xy};\quad xy<-1,x>0,y<0 \end{cases}$

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful, by any chance what is the reasoning behind these identities, I recognize the sum of the tan identities, but I don’t get why some of them add or subtract pi if xy>1 or xy<1.

Comment: @DanLupu we have defined domains for inverse trignometric functions. Now, two positive $\arctan2+\arctan5$ which cannot be negetive so we add $\pi$. If the domains are not defined then there will infinite posible general solution. You can check l[ink](https://byjus.com/question-answer/prove-that-arctan-x-arctan-y-n-arctan-left-frac-x-y-1-xy-right/)